# Fundamental in measure implies convergence in measure

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f_i : [0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ is a measurable
 function. Here the sequence is *fundamental in measure* if for any $
 \varepsilon >0$, $$ \mu\ \bigg(\{ x| \ |f_i(x)-
 f_j(x)| \geq \varepsilon \} \bigg)\rightarrow 0 \ \ast$$ as $i,\ j\rightarrow
 \infty$, where $\mu$ is a Lebesgue measure.

**Problem :** If $f_i$ is fundamental in measure, then there is a
measurable
 function $f$ to which the sequence $f_i$ *converges in measure*.

**Definition :** $f_i$ converges to $f$ in measure if
$\mu\ \bigg(\{ x|
\ |f_i(x)-
 f(x)| \geq \varepsilon \} \bigg)\rightarrow 0 $ as $i\rightarrow
 \infty$.

**Proof :** Strategy is to construct some subsequence $f_{n_i}$ s.t. $$\mu\ \bigg(\{x|\ |f_{n_i}(x) -
 f_{n_{i+1}} (x)| > \frac{1}{2^i} \} \bigg)<\frac{1}{2^i} $$

From $\ast$ we have $f_{n_1},\ f_{n_2}$. But I can not proceed any
more. How can we construct $f_{n_3}$ ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each fixed $i$ there exists a smallest $n_i$ such that for all $n,m\ge n_i$ you have that
$$
\mu\left(\left\{x : |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| > 2^{-i}\right\}\right) < 2^{-i}.
$$
Now, observe that $n_i$ is non-decreasing. So, your relation holds for all $i$.